What will happen to the parachain lease deposit when Agile Coretime is activated?
Says here that active leases will be credited coretime for the duration of their lease. It's unclear whether or not the deposit made for the parachain lease will be paid back. Is that the case?

The deposit for the lease will be paid back, when the lease is ended. With the switch to Coretime, all leases will be migrated to the Coretime chain. There they will stay valid and get "free" Coretime until the lease has ended.

In our case it seems our lease ended without us getting coretime on time, so I cannot find a way to acquire core time as well as to get back the reserved deposit. Is there a way to either release the reserve or get coretime?
